# Use SignalR in WebApi .Net Core 2?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, signalr, .net-core, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to use SignalR in a WebApi .Net Core 2 project.
So, I want to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` package , But I can't find it in `www.nuget.org`
How can I Use SignalR in a WebApi .Net Core 2 project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check "Include prerelease":
[image]

More details how to use:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/09/14/announcing-signalr-for-asp-net-core-2-0/